# The browser reports an error when referencing the geojson file

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

When referencing geojson, the browser reports an error as follows

```
Error {status: 404, url: 'https://domain/resource/point.geojson', name: 'e', message: 'Not Found'}message: "Not Found"name: "e"status: 404url: "https://domain/resource/point.geojson"[[Prototype]]: Objectcause: undefinedconstructor: ƒ Error()stackTraceLimit: 10arguments: (...)caller: (...)captureStackTrace:
```

My JS code is as follows

```
map.on('load', function () {

map.addSource('places', {
'type': 'geojson',
'data': 'https://domain/json/point.geojson'
});

map.addLayer({
'id': 'places',
'type': 'circle',
'source': 'places',
'paint': {
'circle-color': '#FF6464',
'circle-radius': 5,
'circle-stroke-width': 0.8,
'circle-stroke-color': '#ffffff'
}
});
```

The geojson data is as follows

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "description": "<strong>test1</strong><p>2015,2016<br><a href=\"https://domain/77.html\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"Opens in a new window\">test</a></p><img src=\"https://domain/img/2019/04/25/816202630847470.jpeg\" alt=\"test\" width=\"220\" height=\"139\">"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          103.93,
          33.26
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "description": "<strong>test2</strong><p>2007~2015,2016,2017,2018<br></p><img src=\"https://domain/img/2019/04/25/816202630847470.jpeg\" alt=\"test\" width=\"220\" height=\"139\">"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          116.46,
          39.92
        ]
      }
    },
```

I checked the official examples and the sample geojson data, and also verified the correctness of the genjson data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward: you're getting a 404 error (file not found) accessing https://domain/resource/point.geojson. That URL (or whatever the real one is) is not correct.